# .net process start an Internet Explorer on top

Tags: .net, windows, forms, process.start

I am dealing with a .NET Windows Form based application product. In this application I can add process.start to launch an Internet Explorer session. However somehow the IE session is always opened at the background. Is there a way that I can force it to stay front to the end users? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way.
You have to use pinvoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[Fact]
public void OpenIeAsTopWindow()
{
    Process process = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://google.com");
    var HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

All the definitions are from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos)